# avoid paging on GridView (on button (on export))

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //export
{
    GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
    GridViewExportUtil.Export("Сводка.xls", this.GridView2);
    GridView2.AllowPaging = true;
}
```

I need to avoid paging for XLS export :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve like this... have a try please

```
protected void btnExportExl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grd.Allowpaging = false;
    grd.DataBind(); // you need to rebind the gridview
    grd.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    grd.Allowpaging = true;//Again do paging to gridview
    grd.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: ye, just rebind after changing paging helps , thank you a lot <3